# how to make variable hold the value taken from one procedure to be used in another procedure in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a package with two procedures 
in same package.

1. `p_set_values (pn_id_number IN number)`
2. `p_get_values (prc_records OUT sys_refcursor)`

`p_set_values (pn_id_number IN number)`
  inserts data in to my_table where `id_number = pn_id_number`

`p_get_values (prc_records OUT sys_refcursor)` - this procedure has to select the value from my_table where id_number = pn_id_number   (Note: same id number which is used to insert the value ,now used to set the values inserted.)

I have declared package level variable and assigned as `ln_id_number = pn_id_number`.

Now when using this 'ln_id_number' in second procedure, the value of ln_id_number is nothing when checked using dbms_putput.putline(ln_id_number)

Please help me to do this,

Procedures are as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pck_exit_info
IS
  ln_id_number po010.polref%TYPE;

  PROCEDURE p_set_values(pn_id_number IN number
                        ,pv_exit_option IN  VARCHAR2)
  IS
    ln_system_date cs340.sysdte%TYPE;
    lv_audaplcde   package_audits.audit_application_code%TYPE;
    ln_audstfno    package_audits.audit_staff_number%TYPE;
    ln_audupdid    NUMBER;
    lv_exit_option VARCHAR2(1);
  BEGIN
    ln_system_date    := pck_system_context.f_get_system_date;
    ln_id_number      := pn_id_number;
    dbms_output.put_line(ln_id_number);

    SELECT AUDUPDID_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO ln_audupdid FROM DUAL;

    IF pv_exit_option = 'LE' THEN
      lv_exit_option := 'L';
    ELSE
      lv_exit_option := 'S';
    END IF;

    SELECT audit_application_code,audit_staff_number
      INTO lv_audaplcde,ln_audstfno
      FROM package_audits
      WHERE process = 'PCK_LEAVERS'
        AND subprocess ='DEFAULT';

    INSERT INTO my_table
      VALUES(pn_id_number
             ,ln_system_date
             ,lv_exit_option
             ,ln_audupdid
             ,ln_system_date
             ,lv_audaplcde
             ,ln_audstfno);
  END set_employer_exit_info;

  PROCEDURE p_get_values(prc_records OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
  BEGIN
    /*dbms_output.put_line('ID inside get employer');
    dbms_output.put_line(ln_id_number);*/

    OPEN prc_records FOR 
      SELECT *
      FROM   my_table
      WHERE  polref = ln_id_number;
     -- CLOSE  prc_policy;
  END get_employer_exit_info;
END pck_exit_info;
```

Comment: Why aren't you just passing `pn_id_number` as a parameter to the second procedure? This doesn't seem like a good use for package state, which is only visible within a session anyway. Are both calls made from the same session now?

Comment: web is passing id_number to insert the values , and then it want to see what values are being inserted  using the id_number it passed to the first procedure .

Comment: If it's the same session then you presumably still know the ID from the web page so can pass it again; if it's a different session then the package won't know it either as the state (package-level variable) is session-specific. Although if the two calls are back-to-back you could combine them anyway, maybe.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanx , but as per i was asked , to use global variable (i tried wit declaring variable in specification of package.
As of now can you please tell me ,in this kind if scenario , how i can maintain the value in that package level variable , or if global variable required , if call is from same session.
Thank you

Comment: Your code won't compile because the names in the `EXIT` statements associated with the procedures don't match the procedure names. Other than that, @AlexPoole has already covered the issue of 'have to make both calls in the same session'. Best of luck.

Comment: [Here's a quck demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd0f5/1) showing the concept works as you expect in a single session. So I suspect you don't really have a single *database* session; since you mention a web page, perhaps you have a connection pool?

Comment: as it was already said, this will work only in the same session. could you please explain the business logic behind it, because trying to set this globaly for different sessions doesn't make much sense: in different session the procedures will very likely be called with different id's , so how would you know which id corresponds to your process?